# LayoutParams of EditText inside ListView does not work correctly, cannot type any characters in edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, layoutparams

I have a list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.phongponix.trackingbodybuilding.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvExerciseList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
       ></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/containerTest">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgExcercisePhoto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExerciseName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlRecordContainer"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvExcerciseRecords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_panel"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I use Adapter for my List as below:

```
if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExerciseName);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.first_panel);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsWeight = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(convertDpToPixel(activity, 30), convertDpToPixel(activity, 20));
            layoutParamsWeight.setMargins(0, 0, convertDpToPixel(activity, 5), convertDpToPixel(activity, 5));
            EditText etWeight = new EditText(activity);
            etWeight.setWidth(convertDpToPixel(activity, 30));
            etWeight.setHeight(convertDpToPixel(activity, 20));
            //etWeight.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsWeight);
            etWeight.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorEditTextBox));
            etWeight.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            etWeight.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            //etWeight.setId(currentWeightID);
            container.addView(etWeight);

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlRecordContainer);
            renderRecordItemHead(activity, relativeLayout);
            renderRecordItem(activity, relativeLayout, currentWeightID);

            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvExcerciseRecords);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(trackingPlanHorizontalAdapter);


        }
```

As the picture below, if i comment out(dont use) LayoutParams, i can type and see the characters in my EditText. If i use LayoutParams for EditText, i cannot type in. The keyboard appears when i click on EditText and then it lost focus so whenever i touch the keyboard, it show nothing.

[image]

Comment: _do not take my words seriously_ your question does not somehow make sense, if you do not apply layoutParams the ViewGroup applies a default params which is `Wrap_CONTENT` if you(phongtran) apply layoutparam you give it definite sizes `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(convertDpToPixel(activity, 30)` that is why they are acting like that, im i right?

Comment: is keyboard visible when you are clicking on edittext in which layoutparams are applied??

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem some days before. But Apparently it was actually getting edited but because of default padding and text size of EditText it was not fitting in the layoutparams I have provided and it was cropping the extra part so it was invisible to me. Try to set textsize small and padding 0. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a edittext view in the XML?

```
<EditText
android:id = @+id/"edit_ text"
android:text = "Edit text here"
android:layout_width = 100dp
android:layout_height = 100dp
```

Comment: I want to dynamically generate view in code.
Yes, i'm thinking about change the way rendering layout now.

Comment: Yeah why dynamically generate the edit text but not the other layout fields?